# GMP library floating point data type

Tags: c++, double, radix, gmp

I installed the GMP library to replace `double` and`float` with other base-10 floating point data types. Can anyone tell me what those data type will be? And maybe give me a tutorial on how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

use mpf_class from gmpxx.h. Look [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gmp/gmp_73.html)